# Encrypting text in Android (Java)

Tags: java, android

Please help me to correct the code. The string is not getting encrypted.

```
private static String Encrypt(String val)    
{    
    int len = val.length();    
    int[] k = new int[len];    
    for (int n = 0; n < (len-1); n++)    
        k[n] += 5;    
    val = k.toString();  
    return val;    
}
```

Comment: Huh, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between encryption and encoding?

Answer (score 2):

You are adding 5 to an array you have not initialized yourself, meaning it holds all zeroes.

I guess you're trying to implement the [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)? For that, the original string should come in somewhere. Also, you can't change a String's value. Furthermore, you should consider wrapping around at 255 so not to get outside of the valid char range (0..255)

A working version of your function could e.g. look like this:

```
private static String Encrypt(String val) {
    StringBuffer sb;
    for (int n = 0; n < val.length(); n++) {
        sb.Append((char)((val.charAt(n) + 5) % 255));
    }
    sb.toString();
}
```

Two side notes:

1. I hope you're not doing this for an area where security is any concern? Because the Caesar cipher has been broken long ago; also, using a fixed key is the opposite of secure.
   Instead, please consider using an existing algorithm which is currently deemed secure (like AES).
2. Your code formatting makes it easy to misinterpret what the code is actually doing; since there are no parenthesis, the for loop will only actually repeat the one line `k[n] = ...`, but your indentation suggests otherwise...

Comment: thanks a lot for your information.. here i have an assignment to increase 5 letter in each word (need encrypt and decrypt). so i was trying to make. will check and let you know. Sorry if i am wrong.

Comment: hi i am getting error for this code also. As I am working for android. When I debug and simulator its throwing error force close. if i remove this it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an uninitialized array. You should use the `char` values that come from input `String`.

Also you are converting `int[]` to `String` wrong. It should be like this:

```
private static String Encrypt(String val) {
    int len = val.length();
    char[] k = new char[len];
    for (int n = 0; n < len; n++) {
        k[n] = (char)(val.charAt(n) + 5);
    }
    return new String(k);
}
```

Example run:

```
String hidden = Encrypt("1234"); // hidden = "6789"
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. i am checking on this. Will update you the status

Comment: hi here K assignment is not allowing "return new String(k);" its throwing error to remove "k".

Comment: now here made it too "return k.toString();". but its not getting encrypt .. pls help

Comment: It should be `return new String(k);`. Just copy paste whole function, it works.

Comment: hi.. i am getting output for 1234 - " @|@8@A@.. :( for your code.

Comment: Not possible, i tested this function, it works. You must have a problem somewhere else...How do you call it, how do you print the output to log?

Comment: i am testing for android mobile application in emulator (eclipse). i need to ecrypt message before sending. So i am trying to do that."String message3= Encrypt(message);
                
                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message3.length()>0) 
                 
                    sendSMS(phoneNo, message3);                
                    else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }"

Comment: I don't know where the problem is, but this function works. Check: http://ideone.com/CO1JF